# How to obtain refresh token from Google OAuth

Tags: google-oauth

I have been trying to understand how Google OAuth works and can't find a way to obtain refresh token from Google.
I am using Spring Boot and I have configured:

```
.oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                .and()
                .redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                .and()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
                .and()
                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);
```

Further down I am trying to use Google Libraries:

```
AuthorizationCodeFlow authorizationCodeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
                .Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(),
                clientId,
                clientSecret,
                SCOPES)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .setApprovalPrompt("force")
                .build();
```

And then I am using the below code to obtain a refresh token, but I have no idea where I find the authorizationCode.

```
TokenResponse response = authorizationCodeFlow
.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode)
                .execute();
```

Should I see this code in the onAuthenticationSuccess like below?

```
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String authorizationCode = request.getParameter("code");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    .loginPage("/login")
    .userInfoEndpoint()
        .userService(oauthUserService)
    .and()
    .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
 
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
 
            CustomOAuth2User oauthUser = (CustomOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
 
            userService.processOAuthPostLogin(oauthUser.getEmail());
 
            response.sendRedirect("/list");
        }
    })
```

The onAuthenticationSuccess() method will be called by Spring OAuth2 upon successful login using Google, so here we can perform our custom logics – by using the UserService class –
I am attaching link for refrence hope this might help you https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/oauth2-login-with-google-example

Answer (score 0):

Inject an instance of OAuth2AuthorizedClientService into your controller:

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;
```

Use the authorizedClientService to exchange the authorization code for a refresh token:

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService
    .loadAuthorizedClient("google", authenticationToken.getName());

OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = authorizedClient.getRefreshToken();
```

// Handle the access token, refresh token, and other information as per your application's requirements